# Execute bash function in a script and get return

Tags: python, subprocess

i want to execute bash function in a script and i want to print the return function.

this is my current code

```
function myfunct() { 
    return 1
}
```

and my python code:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', '. myscript.sh; myfunct'])
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output)
```

i have "None" output, i want 1 output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of a script isn’t streamed to a standard stream. It sets an *exit code*, which you can query via [`process.returncode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode).

Since you aren’t actually reading the script’s standard streams, don’t use `Popen`/`communicate` — use [`run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead:

```
process = subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', '. myscript.sh; myfunct'])
result = process.returncode
```